# Error unpacking extension and Could not upload file in umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco, umbraco6

This error occur while importing template in umbraco

> Could not upload file System.Exception: Error unpacking extension...
>   ---> System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260
>   characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
>   at System.IO.PathHelper.GetFullPathName() at
>   System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32
>   maxPathLength) at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode
>   mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare
>   share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
>   secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath,
>   Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode
>   mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize) at
>   umbraco.cms.businesslogic.packager.Installer.UnPack(String zipName) at
>   umbraco.cms.businesslogic.packager.Installer.Import(String InputFile)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at umbraco.cms.businesslogic.packager.Installer.Import(String InputFile)
>   at umbraco.presentation.developer.packages.Installer.uploadFile(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Steven-Salim/Posts/2012/07/Extending-URL-Limit.aspx) is link you have to change in web.config file